# How do I specify file path for Android's getExternalStorageState()?

Tags: java, android

I'm completely new to Android development and would like to index a file from the Android phone's external storage. I found some old code which used a deprecated method:

```
String file1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/file.blah";
```

I'm trying to rewrite this line and tried the `Environment.getExternalFilesdir` method but got a "cannot find symbol method" error. The only available method seems to be `getExternalStorageState`, but I can't figure out how to pass the file path argument in. How do I rewrite the deprecated code, using `getExternalStorageState` or otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: You can use getExternalFilesDir(null) on all versions of Android and getExternalStorageDirectory() on Android below Q. And you never need to use getExternalStorageState() and certainly not for a path as that is no path.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalFilesdir`. Remove Environment.

Comment: And if the deprecated methid works, it works. Then use it.

Comment: The deprecated method actually works fine, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

For getting directory of public file. you can use like below

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
docFile = new File(storageDir, docFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually getExternalFilesDir() is not a part of Environment bundle. You can call it via the application context.

`String file2 = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("folder")`

The difference between these two are as follows

**getExternalFilesDir()**: 
This will return the path to files folder inside Android/data/data/your_package_name/. It is used to store any required files for your app.

**getExternalStorageDirectory()**: 
This returns the root path of you external SD card.

As far as the deprecation warning is concerned,  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() or Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), are deprecated. They still work, but will be removed soon, so you need to stop using those.